# AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups

Tags: python, pyethapp

My system:

OS: ubuntu 16.04
python version: 2.7

I am following the instructions from here : https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Getting-Started
to install `pyethapp` from Github. However when I tried to run `pyethapp`, it shows this error message:

> "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
>   AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups

I know this has something to deal particularly with my machine and regex but I am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent bug in pycparser: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3187.
There are two workarounds you can try:

`pip install pycparser==2.13`

or if you don't want to downgrade the pycparser:

`pip install cryptography --no-binary pycparser`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By running the first command, the previous error resolved(perhaps) but now I find a new assertion error for all peers when I run pyethapp. The error message I get now is the same error message that I mentioned secondly in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836556/assertionerror-sorry-but-this-version-only-supports-100-named-groups) while installing pyethapp by PyPI. How to resolve this now :/